# Correctly bundled image could not be loaded

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs, webpack

I have a very simple React component, that is supposed to display an image. 
I am also using Webpack for bundling.

It's probably worth noting that I am using **ReactJS.NET**.

Although the webpack bundle builds properly, and the .jpg generated by webpack is viewable (using Windows Photo Viewer, for example), the image does not display in my View.

When I take a peek into inspector, the html structure is built properly, but I am getting:

> "Could not load the image" - when I hover over the image path.

[image: Image error]

I made sure that the image path is correct.

Below is my react component:

```
var React = require('react');
var BackgroundImg = require('./Images/img_fjords.jpg');

class Login extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <img src={BackgroundImg} />
        );
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("Mounted");
    }
}

module.exports = Login;
```

Webpack config:

```
var path = require('path');
var WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, 'App'),
    entry: {
        server: './server',
        client: './client'
    },

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'Built/'),
        publicPath: path.join(__dirname, 'Built/'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new WebpackNotifierPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
            {
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
            },
            { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192' },
            { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'jsx-loader?harmony' }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        // Allow require('./blah') to require blah.jsx
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },

    externals: {
        // Use external version of React (from CDN for client-side, or
        // bundled with ReactJS.NET for server-side)
        react: 'React'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved thanks to help from @Luggage.

The webpack.config was wrong, it should have been:

```
output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'Built/'),
        publicPath: 'Built/',
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
```

Comment: Had a feeling it was a bundling issue. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't see your webpack config, but I'm assuming your using all the correct loaders (file-loader, extract-loader, html-loader, url-loader)? The way I handle it is using the [webpack-copy-plugin](https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin) to copy over my images folder so relative paths still work.

Comment: I have added the webpack config. Although I don't think this is a bundle issue, as the bundle builds without errors and I get an actual viewable .jpg